# Orchard CMS: Create OnPublished event on existing content type

Tags: orchardcms

I have a content type called Article.  We created the part inside the CMS admin console, so I do not have a corresponding ArticlePart and ArticlePartRecord in the module.  Now I need to run an operation when an article is published.  I'm having a hard time finding out where to intercept the publishing of an item.  I would normally do this in a Handler, but I don't know how to create a handler in this scenario (not having the part and part record objects).

Comment: What do you mean by "We created the part inside the CMS admin console"? How can this be done?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Go to Content Definition and then Create New Type or Create New Part.  You can build the content types and parts from there without using code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just override the `Published` method, like this:

```
protected override void Published(PublishContentContext context) {
    if (context.ContentType == "Article") {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This might work.  I'll try it out.  I should also mention that the Article is a ContentType, not part.  I mis-spoke in my original comment, but I think I can do the same for content types.

Comment: Where would this go?  I had something very similar to your pre-edited answer in a Handler class.

Comment: What I did to fix it was basically the initial answer that was edited here.  I have:    `OnPublished<ContentItem>((context, part) =>
{
    if (part.TypeDefinition.Name == "Article")
    {
        //stuff
    }
}`

Comment: If its about the **type**, it would be better to use the said solution. It depends on what you really want, but basically it does the same thing in this case

Answer (score 0):

Just for those who are new, create a class and add below code.

Make sure to inherit from `ContentHandlerBase` class.

also add `services.AddScoped<IContentHandler, MyCustomPublishHandler>();` to startup class.

And Done!

```
public class MyCustomPublishHandler : ContentHandlerBase
{
    private readonly IContentDefinitionManager _contentDefinitionManager;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyCustomPublishHandler(
        IContentDefinitionManager contentDefinitionManager,
        ILogger<ContentPartHandlerCoordinator> logger)
    {
        _contentDefinitionManager = contentDefinitionManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task PublishedAsync(PublishContentContext context)
    {
        // do something
        var contentTypeDefinition = _contentDefinitionManager.GetTypeDefinition(context.ContentItem.ContentType);
        _logger.LogInformation($"published {contentTypeDefinition.DisplayName}");
    }
}
```